# Creating points while using Mathematica's Table Function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to plot points that I've created in a table in mathematica but for some reason one component of my points seems to have double braces around it while the other only has one as below:

```
{{x},y},{{x1},y1}....{{xn},yn}
```

and list plot will not recognize these as points and will not plot them.
Here is my mathematica code:

```
Remove["Global`*"]
b = .1;
w = 1;
Period = 1;
tstep = 2 Pi/Period;
s = NDSolve[{x''[t] + b x'[t] - x[t] + x[t]^3 - .5 Cos[w t] == 0, 
 x'[0] == 0, x[0] == 0}, x[t], {t, 0, 1000}, MaxSteps -> Infinity];
x[t_] = x[t] /. s
data = Table[Evaluate[{x'[t], .5}], {t, 0, 1000, tstep}]
ListPlot[data]
```

I've also tried using the command

```
ListPlot[Flatten[Table[Evaluate[{x'[t], .5}], {t, 0, 1000, tstep}]]]
```

to no avail as well as

```
ListPlot[Table[Evaluate[{Flatten[x'[t]], .5}], {t, 0, 1000, tstep}]]]
```

How can I remove the `{}`?

Comment: While you're allowed to edit your own questions, it is somewhat bad form to remove so much of them that the answers appear to be answering a completely different question as they are privy to details no longer present. Hence, I rolled it back to the previous version.

Comment: To clarify, the revised version is lacking enough detail to be able to answer it. If you had posted that version initially, you would have been asked for all the details you original question had. Also, it is very likely it would have been voted down, precisely because it could not have been answered in that form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleagues are correct, but I think there is more that can be said.  First, to your actual question.  The output of [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NDSolve.html?q=NDSolve&lang=en) is a list of the form

```
{{x[t]->InterpolatingFunction[...]}, {x[t]->InterpolatingFunction[...]}, ...}
```

where the second and subsequent replacement rules are only there if more than one solution is present. I have never encountered a case using `NDSolve` where that is true, but it makes the answer consistent with [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Solve.html?q=Solve&lang=en), where multiple solutions is not uncommon.  Therefor, with only one solution, you have a double list, i.e.

```
{{x[t]->InterpolatingFunction[...]}}
```

As per [Mr. Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006547/question-about-creating-points-while-using-mathematicas-table-function/6006848#6006848), you can use [`First`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/First.html?q=First&lang=en), or you can use [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html?q=Part&lang=en), i.e.

```
NDSolve[ ... ][[ 1 ]]
```

which is my preferred method, although it is slightly more difficult to read and may obscure your intent. You should be aware that the [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html?q=InterpolatingFunction&lang=en) that `NDSolve` returns is a function, and it will accept variables directly.  So, the variables on the left hand side of the declarations

```
x[t_] = x[t] /. s
```

and from [Belisarius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006547/question-about-creating-points-while-using-mathematicas-table-function/6006768#6006768)

```
xr[u_] := ((x[t] /. s[[1]]) /. t -> u)
```

are superfluous at best, and the second one requires the replacement to occur every time `xr` is used. Instead, you can declare

```
x = x[t] /. s
```

and then writing `x[t]` afterwards will return `IntepolatingFunction[t]`, exactly like you want.  Then, as [Belisarius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006547/question-about-creating-points-while-using-mathematicas-table-function/6006768#6006768) points out, you can use it, or its derivative, in `Plot` directly, instead of first building a table of values and feeding them into `ListPlot`.

**Edit**: when I first posted this, I didn't notice a quirk with `NDSolve`.  If you explicitly solve for `x[t]` not `x`, then `NDSolve` returns `InterpolatingFunction[...][t]`, but if you just solve for `x` you get what I posted. This quirk allows both the OP's and Belisarius's solutions to function, otherwise the replacement shouldn't occur.

Comment: Please post the code for plotting x'[t]. I don't get it. Tnx!

Comment: @belisarius, it is exactly the same form as you have posted: `Plot[x'[t], {t, 0, 30}]`. See also the second example under "Basic Examples" in the `IntepolatingFunction` [help page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html).

Comment: Thank you guys! All your suggestions were really helpful and I got everything to work!

Answer (score 2):

You may try something along these lines:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
b = .1;
w = 1;
s = NDSolve[{x''[t] + b x'[t] - x[t] + x[t]^3 - .5 Cos[w t] == 0, 
    x'[0] == 0, x[0] == 0}, x[t], {t, 0, 1000}, MaxSteps -> Infinity];

xr[u_] := ((x[t] /. s[[1]]) /. t -> u)
Plot[(xr'[u]), {u, 0, 30}]
```

[image]

But I am not sure what are you trying to get from the `{x'[t], .5}` part

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely that `x'[t]` is returning something of the form `{x_i}`. Try replacing the `data=Table...` line with this

```
data = Table[Evaluate[{First[x'[t]], .5}], {t, 0, 1000, tstep}]
```

An alternative would be to do

```
data=data /. {{x_}, y_} :> {x, y};
```

which uses `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) to replace every occurrence of `{{x_i},y_i}` with `{x_i,y_i}`

**Example:**

[image]

Comment: The problem is not caused by derivative but by NDSolve returning its answer in {{x[t]-> ...}} form. This is done to be consistent with output in the case where more solutions are returned.

Comment: @Sjoerd: Yes, that is correct, but OP just wanted to know how to fix it in the `Table`, and that's what I answered. Fixing the output of `NDSolve` like @Mr. Wizard is also an option, but it does change `x[t]` from a row vector to a column vector, and that might break OP's code later on if it depends on it.

Answer (score 1):

There are arguably better ways to accomplish what you are doing, but that is not what you asked.

To remove the extra `{}`  recognize this comes from the result of `NDSolve`, and therefore use:

```
s = First @ NDSolve[{x''[t] + b x'[t] - x[t] + x[t]^3 - .5 Cos[w t] == 0, 
     x'[0] == 0, x[0] == 0}, x[t], {t, 0, 1000}, MaxSteps -> Infinity];
```